# Android emulator storage space always running out

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am running Android Studio on Mac. Every emulator I create I get the following problem, that the device storage is running out. I have tried the following:

1. Wiping device data.
2. Set internal storage to 5 GB (which should be enough)
3. Went into settings on the emulator and reset all data.
4. Restarted android studio and reinstalled the emulator.

What else can I do?

Thanks